# Do i need to use different library in Arduino?

Tags: keyboard, arduino-uno, hid

I was making an project and i need to use Arduino UNO as HID. So, i installed Keyboard library (version 1.0.4) from library manager and write just basic program in new sketch to test it:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>
void setup() {
  // initialize the Keyboard library
  Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() {
  Keyboard.press('A');
  delay(1000);
  Keyboard.release('A');
  delay(1000);
}
```

I compiled it, but it gives me errors:

```
C:\Users\medic\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202314-8852-isv7gn.mjro\sketch_feb4a\sketch_feb4a.ino: In function 'void setup()':
C:\Users\medic\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202314-8852-isv7gn.mjro\sketch_feb4a\sketch_feb4a.ino:4:3: error: 'Keyboard' was not declared in this scope
   Keyboard.begin();
   ^~~~~~~~
C:\Users\medic\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202314-8852-isv7gn.mjro\sketch_feb4a\sketch_feb4a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
C:\Users\medic\AppData\Local\Temp\.arduinoIDE-unsaved202314-8852-isv7gn.mjro\sketch_feb4a\sketch_feb4a.ino:8:3: error: 'Keyboard' was not declared in this scope
   Keyboard.press('A');
   ^~~~~~~~

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'Keyboard' not found. Does your sketch include the line '#include <Keyboard.h>'?
```

I was searching on the internet and find a solution to install other libraries. I installed other libraries from GitHub and some sites to try them, but it didn't work.

Comment: the Keyboard library is for boards with MCU with USB peripheral. for example Arduino Leonardo